Unable to read TIFF data in QField
I am trying to upload my QGIS project to QField Cloud. Unfortunately I always get an error concerning the TIFF file.
This is the error:
Warning! Your QGIS project may not work as expected on QField.
Layer "B_UAV30_TIF_0008_20230429" has an error with code "invalid_dataprovider": Cannot open GDAL dataset /tmp/tmpv42flu9k/files/B_UAV30_TIF_0008_20230429.tif: /tmp/tmpv42flu9k/files/B_UAV30_TIF_0008_20230429.tif: /tmp/tmpv42flu9k/files/B_UAV30_TIF_0008_20230429.tif:Cannot read TIFF header Check the latest "process_projectfile" job logs for more info and reupload the project files with the required changes.

Does someone know an answer to this?
